# Get memory addresses using IDAPython

Tags: disassembly, ida

In my code, I am using `idc.GetOpnd(ea,0)` and `idc.GetOpnd(ea,1)` to get the 2 operands of an instruction. However, if its a `call` (or `jmp`) instruction, I am getting symbols like `_perror` and `loc_8083BA9`.

Using IDAPython, is it possible to remove all the symbols and deal only with memory locations.

Answer (score 8):

Two options:

1. Use [`LocByName`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/255.shtml) to resolve names to addresses
2. Use [`GetOperandValue`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/277.shtml) instead of `GetOpnd` to get the value of the operand instead of its display string.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `GetOperandValue` works fine for `call` and `jmp` instructions. However, for something like this `mov [esp+5Ch+handler],offset aNoCertificateP`, I am getting `mov 4,136298879`. which is not desired. In this case, I just want to resolve `handler` and  `offset aNoCertificateP` to their respective memory locations. Is that possible to do?

Comment: In your example `handler` is a stack address. Therefore it does not have a real memory address. 136298879 is the proper address of aNoCertificateP, just print it out in hex to see the familiar representation.

Comment: Thanks again, In my example, handler is `handler= dword ptr -58h`. So is it possible to replace `handler` with `-58h`. So in the original operand, I get something like `[esp+5Ch-58h]`. I think this can be done by parsing each operand and replace `vars` with their corresponding values. However, parsing each operand is very costly, is there any 'smart' way to accomplish this.  Thanks